# Django get all rows with same value in column

Tags: sql, django, dataset

how can I filter in Django to get a data row one times if the same value in on column?

```
columns: 
a | b
x | y
a | y
y | s
```

Want one data row set with y (b) and one data row set with s (b).

If not clear what I mean I edit with SQL script...
EDIT: `SELECT DISTINCT b FROM table;`

Comment: I don't know about others, but it's not clear to me, so some additional information would be nice.

Comment: added some sql script. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to be blind... 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Have a nice day.

Comment: Does this mean you found [the answer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) yourself?